# TypeScript mapped types: from list of both objects and strings to a key-value object

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I'm trying to write a mapped type that takes a list which can contain both objects ("definitions") and strings. String values are limited to a set of strings that refer to existing hard coded definitions. The resulting type should be an object where the keys are collected from that input list;

- for list elements of type string, use that string
- for list elements of type object, use the `name` property from that object

Here is my current code:

```
type CustomDefinition = {
    name: string;
    units: string | null;
};

const predefinitions = {
    'AUTOPILOT_AIRSPEED_ACQUISITION': {
        name: 'AUTOPILOT_AIRSPEED_ACQUISITION',
        units: 'Bool',
        settable: false,
    },
    'AUTOPILOT_AIRSPEED_HOLD': {
        name: 'AUTOPILOT_AIRSPEED_HOLD',
        units: 'Bool',
        settable: false,
    },
    'AUTOPILOT_AIRSPEED_HOLD_CURRENT': {
        name: 'AUTOPILOT_AIRSPEED_HOLD_CURRENT',
        units: 'Bool',
        settable: false,
    },
} as const;

type PredefinitionName = keyof typeof predefinitions;

type PredefinedValuesResult<SimVars extends PredefinitionName[]> = {
    [VarName in SimVars[number]]: string;
};

type CustomValuesResult<SimVars extends CustomDefinition[]> = {
    [VarName in SimVars[number]['name']]: string;
};

function getPredefinedValue<ReqValues extends PredefinitionName[]>(requestedValues: ReqValues): PredefinedValuesResult<ReqValues> {
    return {} as PredefinedValuesResult<ReqValues>; 
}

function getCustomValues<ReqValues extends CustomDefinition[]>(requestedValues: ReqValues): CustomValuesResult<ReqValues> {
    return {} as CustomValuesResult<ReqValues>; 
}

const predfinedValuesResult = getPredefinedValue([
    'AUTOPILOT_AIRSPEED_ACQUISITION', 
    'AUTOPILOT_AIRSPEED_HOLD_CURRENT',
]);

const customValues = getCustomValues([
    { name: 'CUSTOM_VARIABLE', units: 'degrees' }
]);

console.log(
    predfinedValuesResult.AUTOPILOT_AIRSPEED_ACQUISITION, 
    predfinedValuesResult.AUTOPILOT_AIRSPEED_HOLD_CURRENT, 
);

console.log(
    customValues.CUSTOM_VARIABLE, 
);

// Un-implemented functionality:

const customAndPredefinedValues = getCustomAndPredefinedValues([
    'AUTOPILOT_AIRSPEED_ACQUISITION',
    { name: 'CUSTOM_VARIABLE', units: 'degrees' }
]);

console.log(
    customAndPredefinedValues.AUTOPILOT_AIRSPEED_ACQUISITION, // should autocomplete
    customAndPredefinedValues.CUSTOM_VARIABLE, // should autocomplete
)
```

Using `PredefinedValuesResult` and `CustomValuesResult` alone works fine, but I want to allow the user to specify a list of both custom definitions and referring strings.

Would this be possible?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m3KQEm) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jcalz, that's the closest I've been so far! 

What I didn't show in my sample code is that the type of each property is derived from the `dataType` field. In order to do this I need to create a type/interface for the predefinitions, which seem to break it. I have updated your snippet with the rest of the required logic: https://tsplay.dev/wXga1W

Comment: Sorry, wrong URL. https://tsplay.dev/wOXerN

Comment: Looking at it, that's out of scope, it's just the next problem you hit.  You're looking for the `satisfies` operator as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mLAKAW). Could we please just leave the current question scope alone and I'll answer it as-is, and then if you still can't figure out how to proceed you open a new question?

Comment: @jcalz, `satisfies` did the trick! Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to examine the input array elements and use them directly if they are a key of `predefinitions`, or to use their `name` property if they are a `CustomDefinition`.  For example:

```
type Predefinitions = typeof predefinitions;

declare function getCustomAndPredefinedValues<
    const T extends CustomDefinition | keyof Predefinitions>(
        t: T[]
    ): { [K in (
        T extends keyof Predefinitions ? T :
        T extends CustomDefinition ? T["name"] :
        never
    )]: string };
```

Now your function behaves as desired:

```
const customAndPredefinedValues = getCustomAndPredefinedValues([
    'AUTOPILOT_AIRSPEED_ACQUISITION',
    { name: 'CUSTOM_VARIABLE', units: 'degrees' }
]);
/* const customAndPredefinedValues: {
    AUTOPILOT_AIRSPEED_ACQUISITION: string;
    CUSTOM_VARIABLE: string;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAYQK4GcwHsC2ARGAzASwDsCwD0i4BeOAb1DkbiIENMYAuONAJ2IHMA3AyZISYFF14C4AH2ZIANouEgAvqtABjCmjhQeMACb5ipckRTU6IxgHIAggFUAKgHkACgEkAMm5cA+g5eAEoAyh4AopHYQQgAik5eYV4uXm4AcnZc9CBM+cxsnHCOrp6+-kGhEdGxDglJKWmZdgA0tgVipJIlAELo6IptHfkoMGBgLABGisV4LIpj7XlMasv5pe7efoHB4VExAQASbj7Y2TYrBYXsXJvlO1X7tcen5+vXcF0Sd-2Dw1cCmMJtNZlx5osYB9GGsOvdtpU9jVDiczgEEE4QiFIhkXBdcp8bsV4RVdtUDrFUbEMVicXjoZ1xD07H8hgzRuNJjM5gslh1Yeo4CwrDpLGBNOBoPAPIYTIRxBYrDRILB0Hh9LLTArdBKTFpFCxDHA8GItGQKHB+ONkGgsA4iEYZcYtcYAGoLJAwFAAHg6or0LjgMAAHmAYA6rDaMDgteYLfIANYwCBquBOuVmc2WAB8AAoRkwwFwXABtAC6HQAlDk4CWANJwYhwfOA-KBkNhiNwJMp9Xp2NZqwAfjggY4BcY7dD4aMkdQ0dw8rjlBHpYARKx2Guy3Bx62mEQYAA3GA8KtlqRgPhEfhwDSgbS6MBwLTzu0O-vyt0er3WK1gKN30dTUvyMd1FE9FBcxLOFnC2UknmROoGmSVJ0iyBlaCJO4MTCdwAFkAldBwQi8Bxeh8SI2i+Jk7hMfhDC9Ow71AMtK1UAB6AAqF8nxfN9MHtYDnVA8DIJyDo4IeRFyReepElQ5oMkva8hA6XCCKIkiyIoyIVIEVQ1DgLiOIfEB-UGGAADpFHQfgW3yV9bUEj8QOIb8IK9KypIRMlnkOeTGjQzJWjgDiOO4AALdAlCMIUkAwHRMCgWYwz9AShM-dywJ-FArI0txCOI0jyMo0LwqimLFDilgEvQJKUvGGBQErUAgA)